# Finding the correlation of two discrete random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

This problem is from the book, "Introduction to Probability" by Hoel, Port and Stone. It is problem 22 on page 106.
Problem:
A box has $3$ red balls and $2$ black balls. A random sample of size $2$ is drawn without replacement. Let $U$ be the number of
red balls selected drawn and let $V$ by the number of black balls selected. Compute $\rho(U,V)$.
Answer:
Recall the formula:
$$ \rho(U,V) = \frac{ Cov(U,V) }{ \sigma_U \,\,\sigma_V  } $$
So, the first step is to compute the mean of $U$ and the mean of $V$.
\begin{align*}
u_U &= 2\left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
 1\left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
u_U &= \frac{2(3)(2)}{20} + \frac{4}{20}+ \frac{6}{20} = \frac{12 + 4 + 6}{20} = \frac{ 11 } {10} \\
u_V &=
 2 \left( \frac{2}{4} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right) + 1 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
  + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)  \\
u_V &= \frac{4}{12} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} \\
u_V &= \frac{1}{3} + \frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{10} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{3}{5} \\
u_V &= \frac{5 + 3(3)}{5(3)} \\
u_V &= \frac{14}{15} \\
E( U^2 ) &= 2^2 \left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)
 +  1^2 \left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= 4 \left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right) +  \left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= \frac{4(3)(2)}{20} + \frac{4}{20} + \frac{6}{26} = \frac{24}{20} + \frac{4}{20} + \frac{6}{20} \\
E( U^2 ) &= \frac{12}{10} + \frac{2}{10} + \frac{3}{10} \\
E(U^2) &= \frac{17}{10} \\
E( V^2 ) &= 2^2 \left( \frac{2}{4} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right) + 1^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)  \\
E( V^2 ) &= 4 \left( \frac{2}{4} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right) +  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)   \\
E( V^2 ) &=  \frac{8}{12} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} =  \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{10} \\
E( V^2 ) &=  \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{5} = \frac{19}{15}
\end{align*}
Now we can find $\sigma_U$ and $\sigma_V$.
\begin{align*}
\sigma_U^2 &= E(U^2) - u_U^2 = \frac{19}{15} - \left(  \frac{ 11 } {10} \right) ^ 2 \\
\sigma_U^2 &= \frac{19}{15} - \frac{121}{100} = \frac{ 19(100) - 121(15)} {15(100)} \\
\sigma_U^2 &=  \frac{ 85} {15(100)} = \frac{17}{300} \\
\sigma_V^2 &= E(V^2) - u_V^2 =  \frac{19}{15} - \left( \frac{14}{15} \right) ^ 2 \\
\sigma_V^2 &= \frac{19(15) - 14^2}{15^2} = \frac{ 89} {225} \\
Cov(U,V) &= E(UV) - E(U)E(V) \\
E(UV) &= 1(1) P(U = 1, V = 1) = P(U = 1, V = 1) \\
P(U = 1, V = 1) &= \frac{3}{5}\left( \frac{2}{4}\right) + \frac{2}{5}\left( \frac{3}{4 }\right) = \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} \\
P(U = 1, V = 1) &= \frac{3}{10} \\
Cov(U,V) &= \frac{3}{10} - \frac{ 11 } {10} \left( \frac{14}{15}  \right) = \frac{3}{10} - \frac{154}{ 150 } \\
Cov(U,V) &= -\frac{109}{150} \\
\rho(U,V) &= \frac{  -\frac{109}{150}   }  { \sqrt{ \frac{17}{300} } \left( \sqrt{ \frac{ 89} {225} } \right)   } \\
\rho(U,V) &=  -\frac{109 \sqrt{300(225) }}  { 150 \sqrt{ 17(89) }  } =  -\frac{1090 \sqrt{3(225) }}  { 150 \sqrt{ 17(89) }  } \\
\rho(U,V) &=  -\frac{109(15) \sqrt{3 }}  { 15 \sqrt{ 17(89) }  } =  -\frac{109(15) \sqrt{3 }}  { 15 \sqrt{ 1513 }  } \\
\rho(U,V) &= -\frac{109 \sqrt{3 }}  { \sqrt{ 1513 }  }
\end{align*}
Hence $\rho(U,V) < -1$ so my answer cannot be right. The book's answer is:
$$ -1 $$
Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated answer based upon the comments made by Rob Pratt.
Recall the formula:
$$ \rho(U,V) = \frac{ Cov(U,V) }{ \sigma_U \,\,\sigma_V  } $$
So, the first step is to compute the mean of $U$ and the mean of $V$.
\begin{align*}
u_U &= 2\left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
 1\left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
u_U &= \frac{2(3)(2)}{20} + \frac{6}{20}+ \frac{6}{20} = \frac{12 + 6 + 6}{20} = \frac{ 6 } {5} \\
\end{align*}
Now, observe that $u_U + u_V = 2$
\begin{align*}
u_V &=
 2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right) + 1 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
  + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)  \\
u_V &= \frac{4}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} = \frac{16}{20} \\
u_V &=  \frac{4}{5} \\
E( U^2 ) &= 2^2 \left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
1^2 \left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= 4 \left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
 \left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= 4 \left( \frac{6}{20} \right)  +  \left( \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20}  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= \frac{24}{20} + \frac{12}{20}  = \frac{9}{5} \\
%
%
E( V^2 ) &= 2^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right) + 1^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( V^2 ) &= 4 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right) + \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( V^2 ) &= \frac{8}{15} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} = \frac{8}{15} + \frac{6}{10} \\
E( V^2 ) &= \frac{8(10) + 6(15)}{10(15)} \\
E( V^2 ) &= \frac{17}{15} \\
\end{align*}
Now we can find $\sigma_U$ and $\sigma_V$.
\begin{align*}
\sigma_U^2 &= E(U^2) - u_U^2 = \frac{9}{5} - \left(  \frac{ 6 } {5} \right) ^ 2 \\
\sigma_U^2 &= \frac{9(5)}{5} - \frac{36}{25} = \frac{9}{15} \\
\sigma_V^2 &= E(V^2) - u_V^2 =  \frac{17}{15} - \left( \frac{4}{5} \right) ^ 2 \\
\sigma_V^2 &= \frac{17}{15} - \frac{16}{25} = \frac{17(25) - 16(15)}{15(25)} \\
\sigma_V^2 &= \frac{ 185}  { 375 }  = \frac{19}{ 75 }\\
Cov(U,V) &= E(UV) - E(U)E(V) \\
E(UV) &= 1(1) P(U = 1, V = 1) = P(U = 1, V = 1) \\
P(U = 1, V = 1) &= \frac{3}{5}\left( \frac{2}{4}\right) + \frac{2}{5}\left( \frac{3}{4 }\right) = \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} \\
P(U = 1, V = 1) &= \frac{3}{10} \\
Cov(U,V) &= \frac{3}{10} -  \frac{ 6 } {5} \left(  \frac{4}{5} \right) = \frac{3}{10} - \frac{24}{25} \\
Cov(U,V) &= \frac{3(25) - 24(10)}{250} = \frac{15 - 48}{50} \\
Cov(U,V) &= \frac{-33} {50} \\
\rho(U,V) &= \frac{\frac{-33} {50}  }{ \sqrt{   \frac{9}{15}  \left( \frac{19}{ 75 } \right)  }  } \\
\rho(U,V) &= -\frac{ 33 \sqrt{ 15(75) } } { \sqrt{ 9(19) } } =  -\frac{ 33(5) \sqrt{ 3(15) } } { \sqrt{ 9(19) } } \\
\rho(U,V) &= -\frac{ 33(5) \sqrt{ 3(15) } } { 3 \sqrt{ 19 } } = -\frac{11(5) \sqrt{45}}{15} \\
\rho(U,V) &= -\frac{11(3)\sqrt{5}}{3} \\
\rho(U,V) &= -11\sqrt{5}
\end{align*}
Hence $\rho(U,V) < -1$ so my answer cannot be right. The book's answer is
$$ -1 $$
Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated answer based upon the comments made by Rob Pratt.
Recall the formula:
$$ \rho(U,V) = \frac{ Cov(U,V) }{ \sigma_U \,\,\sigma_V  } $$
So, the first step is to compute the mean of $U$ and the mean of $V$.
\begin{align*}
u_U &= 2\left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
 1\left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
u_U &= \frac{2(3)(2)}{20} + \frac{6}{20}+ \frac{6}{20} = \frac{12 + 6 + 6}{20} = \frac{ 6 } {5} \\
\end{align*}
Now, observe that $u_U + u_V = 2$
\begin{align*}
u_V &=
 2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right) + 1 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
  + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)  \\
u_V &= \frac{4}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} = \frac{16}{20} \\
u_V &=  \frac{4}{5} \\
E( U^2 ) &= 2^2 \left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
1^2 \left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= 4 \left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
 \left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= 4 \left( \frac{6}{20} \right)  +  \left( \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20}  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= \frac{24}{20} + \frac{12}{20}  = \frac{9}{5} \\
%
%
E( V^2 ) &= 2^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \right) + 1^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)  \\
E( V^2 ) &=  4 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \right) +  \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)  \\
E( V^2 ) &= \frac{8}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} \\
E( V^2 ) &= 1
\end{align*}
Now we can find $\sigma_U$ and $\sigma_V$.
\begin{align*}
\sigma_U^2 &= E(U^2) - u_U^2 = \frac{9}{5} - \left(  \frac{ 6 } {5} \right) ^ 2 \\
\sigma_U^2 &= \frac{9(5)}{5} - \frac{36}{25} = \frac{9}{15} \\
\sigma_U^2 &= \frac{3}{ \sqrt{15} } \\
\sigma_V^2 &= E(V^2) - u_V^2 =  1 - \left( \frac{4}{5} \right) ^ 2 \\
\sigma_V^2 &= 1 - \frac{16}{25} = \frac{9}{25} \\
\sigma_V &= \frac{3}{5} \\
Cov(U,V) &= E(UV) - E(U)E(V) \\
E(UV) &= 1(1) P(U = 1, V = 1) = P(U = 1, V = 1) \\
P(U = 1, V = 1) &= \frac{3}{5}\left( \frac{2}{4}\right) + \frac{2}{5}\left( \frac{3}{4 }\right) = \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} \\
P(U = 1, V = 1) &= \frac{3}{10} \\
% continue here Bob
Cov(U,V) &=  \frac{3}{10} - \frac{ 6 } {5} \left( \frac{4}{5} \right)  = \frac{3}{10} - \frac{24}{25}\\
Cov(U,V) &=  \frac{3(25) - 240}{250} \\
Cov(U,V) &= -\frac{16}{25} \\
\rho(U,V) &= \frac{ -\frac{16}{25}  }{ \frac{3}{ \sqrt{15} } \,\, \left(  \frac{3}{5} \right)  } =
  -\frac{ 16(5)(\sqrt{15}) }{ 25(9) } \\
\rho(U,V) &= -\frac{16 \sqrt{15}} { 45 }
\end{align*}
Hence $\rho(U,V) < -1$ so my answer cannot be right. The book's answer is
$$ -1 $$
Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated answer based upon the comments made by Rob Pratt.
Recall the formula:
$$ \rho(U,V) = \frac{ Cov(U,V) }{ \sigma_U \,\,\sigma_V  } $$
So, the first step is to compute the mean of $U$ and the mean of $V$.
\begin{align*}
u_U &= 2\left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
 1\left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
u_U &= \frac{2(3)(2)}{20} + \frac{6}{20}+ \frac{6}{20} = \frac{12 + 6 + 6}{20} = \frac{ 6 } {5} \\
\end{align*}
Now, observe that $u_U + u_V = 2$
\begin{align*}
u_V &=
 2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right) + 1 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
  + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)  \\
u_V &= \frac{4}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} = \frac{16}{20} \\
u_V &=  \frac{4}{5} \\
E( U^2 ) &= 2^2 \left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
1^2 \left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= 4 \left( \frac{3}{5}\right) \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  + 
 \left(  \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) + \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= 4 \left( \frac{6}{20} \right)  +  \left( \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20}  \right) \\
E( U^2 ) &= \frac{24}{20} + \frac{12}{20}  = \frac{9}{5} \\
%
%
E( V^2 ) &= 2^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \right) + 1^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)  \\
E( V^2 ) &=  4 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \right) +  \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)  \\
E( V^2 ) &= \frac{8}{20} + \frac{6}{20} + \frac{6}{20} \\
E( V^2 ) &= 1
\end{align*}
Now we can find $\sigma_U$ and $\sigma_V$.
\begin{align*}
\sigma_U^2 &= E(U^2) - u_U^2 = \frac{9}{5} - \left(  \frac{ 6 } {5} \right) ^ 2 \\
\sigma_U^2 &= \frac{9(5)}{5} - \frac{36}{25} = \frac{9}{15} \\
\sigma_U^2 &= \frac{3}{ \sqrt{15} } \\
\sigma_V^2 &= E(V^2) - u_V^2 =  1 - \left( \frac{4}{5} \right) ^ 2 \\
\sigma_V^2 &= 1 - \frac{16}{25} = \frac{9}{25} \\
\sigma_V &= \frac{3}{5} \\
Cov(U,V) &= E(UV) - E(U)E(V) \\
E(UV) &= 1(1) P(U = 1, V = 1) = P(U = 1, V = 1) \\
P(U = 1, V = 1) &= \frac{ {3 \choose 1} {2 \choose 1} }{ {5 \choose 2} } = \frac{3(2)}{ \frac{5(4)}{2} } \\
P(U = 1, V = 1) &= \frac{6}{10} = \frac{3}{5} \\
% continue here Bob
Cov(U,V) &=  \frac{3}{5} - \frac{ 6 } {5} \left( \frac{4}{5} \right)  = \frac{3}{5} - \frac{24}{25}\\
Cov(U,V) &= \frac{15}{25} - \frac{24}{25} =  -\frac{9}{25} \\
\rho(U,V) &= \frac{  -\frac{9}{25}}{ \frac{3}{ \sqrt{15} } \,\, \left( \frac{3}{5} \right)  } = -\frac{9(5)\sqrt{15}}{3(3)(25)} \\
\rho(U,V) &= -\frac{9\sqrt{15}}{3(3)(5)} \\
\rho(U,V) &= -\frac{ \sqrt{15} }{5} \\
\end{align*}
The book's answer is
$$ -1 $$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Since $U=2-V$, these values are linearly dependent, and $\rho(U,V)=-1$ without calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The means are wrong, and I didn't check the subsequent steps.  We have:
\begin{align}
E[U]&= \frac{2\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{0}+1\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{5}{2}} = \frac{6}{5}\\
E[V]&= \frac{2\binom{3}{0}\binom{2}{2}+1\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{5}{2}} = \frac{4}{5}
\end{align}
As a sanity check, note that $U+V=2$, so $2=E[2]=E[U+V]=E[U]+E[V]$, which your computation violates.

Similarly:
\begin{align}
E[U^2]&= \frac{2^2\binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{0}+1^2\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{5}{2}} = \frac{9}{5}\\
E[V^2]&= \frac{2^2\binom{3}{0}\binom{2}{2}+1^2\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{5}{2}} = 1
\end{align}

Also:
$$E[UV]= \frac{1\cdot 1\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{5}{2}} = \frac{3}{5}$$

So $$
\rho(U,V)=\frac{E[UV]-E[U]E[V]}{\sqrt{E[U^2]-E[U]^2}\sqrt{E[V^2]-E[V]^2}}
=\frac{3/5-(6/5)(4/5)}{\sqrt{9/5-(6/5)^2}\sqrt{1-(4/5)^2}}=-1
$$

---

**Update:**
Here's an alternative approach that uses properties of covariance and variance to shorten the computations, as suggested in the comment by @NCh.
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(U,V) &= \text{Cov}(U,2-U) = \text{Cov}(U,-U) = -\text{Cov}(U,U) = -\text{Var}(U) \\
\text{Var}(V)&=\text{Var}(2-U)=\text{Var}(-U)=(-1)^2\text{Var}(U)=\text{Var}(U) \\
\rho(U,V) &= \frac{\text{Cov}(U,V)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(U)}\sqrt{\text{Var}(V)}}=\frac{-\text{Var}(U)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(U)}\sqrt{\text{Var}(U)}}=-1
\end{align}

Comment: I have fixed the errors in the calculations of the means of $U$ and $V$ but my answer is still wrong.

Comment: Your $E[V^2]$ is wrong.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Is this equation right: $E( V^2 ) = 2^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) \right) + 1^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)$

Comment: I now think this is right: $E( V^2 ) = 2^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \right) + 1^2 \left( \frac{2}{5} \left( \frac{3}{4} \right) 
+ \frac{3}{5} \left( \frac{2}{4} \right)  \right)$

Comment: I have updated my work but my answer is still wrong. I feel I am getting closer.

Comment: Your $E[UV]$ is wrong.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Based upon your comments, I have updated my answer. However, I am still getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Your $\sigma_U^2$ is wrong.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I now have the right answer. If you think I should, I will post my answer.